# Expo ReactNative Firebase Get authenticated user and profile in one go

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am new to Expo and ReactNative. At the moment, I am developing a mobile app that utilizes Firebase Auth and Firestore for authentication and user profile. From googling, I found a solution to use ContextProvider for the Firebase Auth. I tried to adjust the code to obtain the profile at the same time.

This is the code for AuthenticatedUserProvider.js

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const AuthenticatedUserContext = createContext({});

export const AuthenticatedUserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null);

    return (
        <AuthenticatedUserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser, profile, setProfile }}>
            {children}
        </AuthenticatedUserContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And I read the `profile` on the `RotNavigator.js` below

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider, IconRegistry } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { EvaIconsPack } from '@ui-kitten/eva-icons';
import { auth, fs } from '../config/firebase';
import { AuthenticatedUserContext } from './AuthenticatedUserProvider';
import AuthStack from './AuthStack';
import HomeStack from './HomeStack';
import { default as theme } from '../orange-theme.json';

export default function RootNavigator() {
    const { user, setUser, profile, setProfile } = useContext(AuthenticatedUserContext);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        // onAuthStateChanged returns an unsubscribe
        const unsubscribeAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async authenticatedUser => {
            try {
                if (authenticatedUser) {
                    await setUser(authenticatedUser)
                    const response = await fs.collection("members").doc(authenticatedUser.uid).get();

                    if (response.exists) {
                        let data = response.data();
                        // console.log(data);
                        await setProfile(data);
                        // console.log(profile);
                    }
                } else {
                    await setUser(null);
                    await setProfile(null);
                }

                setIsLoading(false);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

        // unsubscribe auth listener on unmount
        return unsubscribeAuth;
    }, []);

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
            </View>
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
            <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
            <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={{ ...eva.light, ...theme }}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    {user ? <HomeStack /> : <AuthStack />}
                </NavigationContainer>
            </ApplicationProvider >
        </>
    );
}
```

The code looks like working except that if I log in, sometimes I saw an error on profile = null and cannot read the profile but then it refreshed by itself and back to run properly.

Can someone suggest the correct way to display the profile from Firestore?

The reason I do it like this is I want an efficient way of displaying the profile since HomeStack has 3 screens that would need to display some parts of the profile on each screen.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you really need the auth user and profile separate? This is happening because you have two setState calls and they're not guaranteed to fire together so you'll have some edge cases where one fires but not the other, and you'll see issues like you're seeing. What do you need from the auth user record? Just the uid? Why not add that to the profile and ONLY `setProfile`. Then when the user logs out, same idea - just `setProfile(null)`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I don't need a separate user. It is true that I only need the `uid`. I will try to implement this.

Comment: @I'mJoeToo but I make the call to setUser using await, isn't that mean that need to wait for setUser to finish before calling setProfile? and to render after the setProfile is finish loaded?

Comment: For promises, `await` means that the line would execute and finish before moving on to the next one. But in React, `useState` isn't promise-based. When you `setUser` and set other states, they're added to a queue and then executed later - within microseconds, but in no guaranteed order which is why you intermittently get these weird states. For `useState`, your `await` doesn't do anything here.

Comment: hi @I'mJoeToo thank you for the great explanation. I think I fixed my problem by changing this line {profile ? <HomeStack /> : <AuthStack />} . so instead of relied on the user to be set, I relied on the profile. if they are login but the profile is not set yet, they will be asked to login again. but so far with this fix, I can get rid of the error message